# Angular2 How can i add two values when its in *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Here im having textBox in *ngFor="let abc in Apple;let i = index"

```
<tr  *ngFor="let abc in Apple;let i = index">

<td>        <input matInput  name="UnitofPrice"  [(ngModel)] = "BillofQty[i]">
</td>
<td>{{BillofQty[i]+1}}
```

Here im Getting OutPust as If i Enter12 Its Comming AS 121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<td>
   {{BillofQty[i]*1 + 1*1}}
</td>
```

Comment: An alternative syntax: `{{ +BillofQty[i] + 1 }}`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because values that come from an input field are always strings. So BillofQty[i] is a string. And using the + operator on a string results in the two values being concatenated. So you will first need to convert this value into a number.

If you don't care if it is saved as string or number you could simply put: 
`{{+BillofQty[i]+1}}` or `{{Number(BillofQty[i])+1}}`. This converts your string value in BillofQty[i] to a number.

If you want to save the value as a number directly you will probably have to split your `[(ngModel)]` into `[value]="BillofQty[i]"` and `(ngModelChange)="yourMethod(i)"` where you convert the value to a number in yourMethod and then save it to this.BillofQty[i].